# Angstrom circle not centred

Tags: fonts, siunitx

When using the following code, I note that the circle above the "A" in angstrom is not centred correctly over the "A" but it is too far to the left. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    Additionally, it is accompanied by a drastic change in end-to-end distance of ~3.5 {\si\angstrom} as well as polarity (3 Debye for $cis$ versus 0 Debye for $trans$).
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the OT1 encoding, `\r{A}` is a predefined combination that doesn't use the ring accent, but uses a more complex setup, because the ring should be attached to the A. This setup fails with TeX Gyre Bonum, but it can be fixed.

I also suggest to scale down the font, because it has a rather large x-height; alternatively, you could increase the leading with `\linespread{1.1}` or similar.

You can get numbers with `\SI` in the text font by using `mode=text`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.94]{tgbonum}
\usepackage[mode=text]{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\r}{OT1}{A}{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\char23\cr\noalign{\kern-1.15ex}A\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\r{A}ngstrom or \AA ngstrom \r{A}\r{U} \r{a}\r{u}

Additionally, it is accompanied by a drastic change in
end-to-end distance of~\SI{3.5}{\angstrom} as well as polarity
(3~Debye for \emph{cis} versus 0~Debye for \emph{trans}).

\end{document}
```

Note that using `$word$` is *not* the way to get italics.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The left-offset of the ångström symbol is caused by `tgbonum`. You can fix this by also loading `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` after `tgbonum`.

I also suggest that you use [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)'s provided macro (instead of only using the package to obtain the unit), `\SI`, to properly typeset values with units:

```
$\approx \SI{3.5}{\angstrom}$
```